# Is there a native way to convert a string from any locale to a number?

Tags: javascript

I know that I can convert a number to a string in a specified locale like so

```
(1.2).toLocaleString("de-DE") //-> "1,2"
```

What I don't know, or can't seem to find, is why there isn't a way to go in reverse. For example:

```
("1,2").fromLocaleString("de-DE").toFloat()
```

or

```
parseFloat("1,2", "de-DE")
```

The only solutions I have found to parse a number string from a different locale have been 3rd party plugins. If the browser can convert in one direction, is there a way for it to convert in the other direction?

Comment: Is this what you're looking for https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat maybe?

Comment: I saw that as well, but in every example it is taking a number and turning it into a string. I want to take a string (ex: "1,23") and turn it into a number (1.23). Am I missing something in those docs?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP already knows that such a method does not exist natively in Javascript but wants to know "why". This is something that would need to be addressed by the [TC39](http://www.ecma-international.org/memento/TC39.htm)

Comment: Maybe the way I phrased the question wasn't descriptive enough. I don't actually know THAT I can't do this natively, just that I don't know how I would do that. I'll update the question.

Comment: There is no native method that will reverse [`Number.prototype.toLocaleString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString). You either write your own routine or use a 3rd party solution.

Answer (score 1):

It may be easier to define your own function. Something like this:

```
function parseFloatSeparator(str, sep) {
    sep = sep || ".";
    str = str.replace(new RegExp("[^0-9"+sep+"]","g"),"");
    if( sep != ".") str = str.replace(sep,".");
    return parseFloat(str);
}
```

Comment: It's definitely a solution to the problem i'm describing, but I don't understand why this isn't natively supported which is the intent of my question. Is this not possible to accomplish with native parsing & locales? How and/or why not?